# Installing softwares witout sudo in centos for a single user only?

Tags: linux, sudo, centos6, package-managers

I am using centos 6 for which I am not having sudo access.I have a user account and have full access for that account. Is there a way to install packages/softwares for a particular user in Centos.

Comment: Wont anything you install for user, be limited to that user only ? (unless you modify some init scripts or profiles)

Comment: I am the only user using this system but without sudo access.So i wanna install some packages like emacs,pip for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the executables into your home directory. You may also add it to your PATH variable. Many people has a ~/bin directory for this kind of stuffs.

Comment: say i wanna install emacs I have the source code I did ./configure to my user directory it was .my_packages but there is a issue with the following steps make is saying make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: @Anurag: that's a totally different issue, you're probably on the wrong directory when running the configure/make command.